# What's wrong with Advanced Studies in Contemporary Mathematics (Kyungshang)?

Tags: journals

By some reason the [Journal](http://www.jangjeon.or.kr/menu1/menu1_sub1.html) mentioned in the title is no longer covered by the AMS Math. Reviews. On the MathSciNet web page it says:

Last Issue: 24, no. 1  2014

Indexed cover-to-cover

Status: No longer indexed

The journal, however, still exists and it is still covered by the Zentralblatt. I have written to the journal and the AMS several times already and asked for the reason why the AMS doesn't review this journal any more and I have got no answer from either side!

Does someone know why this journal is no longer indexed?

Comment: I very much doubt that "politics" plays a role. I have no information on this specific case, but the general reason why AMS would stop indexing is clearly stated [here](http://www.ams.org/publications/math-reviews/mrelecjour), and solely revolves on scholarly practices.

Comment: Anton, why not replace the last line by something neutral like "Does someone know why this journal is no longer indexed?"

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, that is a "policy on indexing electronic journals", and this is a hard-copy journal -- do you really think that the journal is changing the articles after publication without documentation, as would be needed for the linked policy to be relevant?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There has been an explosion in new allegedly "scholarly" journals because they are profitable and many university libraries have lost control over their inventory due to the "big deal" they were trapped into a decade ago where they were lured by lower prices into relinguishing autonomy over subscription decisions, currently made in a centralized fashion.

The result is a rapid decline in quality and a rapid increase in quantity. MathSciNet had to deal with this by terminating their coverage of numerous journals and not merely this particular item from Kyungshang. Just because the title the folks in Kyungshang chose is very similar to an AMS publication (*Contemporary Mathematics*), which is a common practice among the new crop of so-called scholarly journals, is not a reason to suspect foul play on the part of the AMS.

Comment: It is obvious why AMS does not index the vast number of "pay to publish" so-called journals run  by predatory publishers. But it does not really explain why it would *stop* indexing a legitimate journal.

Comment: @Gordon, as far as I know the feature you mentioned is field-dependent. In mathematics it is unusual to charge a fee for publication, in physics it seems to be quite common. Therefore publication fees for authors do not necessarily indicate a lousy journal. It is hard for me to tell whether the Kyungshang thing is a quality publication. Do you know for sure?